# How to bind to a remote IP port via internet?

Tags: networking

I have two servers in my network:
A: 192.168.0.1, B: 192.168.0.1

Now I want to run HTTPD on server B, but access it using 192.168.0.1, which means, make HTTPD bind to 192.168.0.1:80 on server B. Is that possible? How to make it?

I have considered iptables and SSH tunnel, but I don’t know how to do it.

Note: Things like reverse proxy or sniproxy are not considered, as they do not fit my situation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot have two separate machines with the same IP address on your network.

Comment: @dobey I understand, I just need port 80. Also It is OK to bind to a local port on server B, but forward that port to server A.

Comment: You can probably do what you want via several methods, from NAT to iptables to a proxy to ssh . Your question is not very clear as to what you want to do and how, as has already been pointed out both should not have the same ip address so we are confused on what you want and why neither ssh or NAT or a proxy server do not fit your needs.

Comment: You do not seem to understand what dobey said: if you have to computers on your network, they CAN NOT both have the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a server on one IP address bind to a port on another IP address owned by another host, no.

If what you're asking is that host A is your router/gateway, and host B is the actual hardware where you want to run a server, you will need to configure host A to forward connection requests on port 80 to port 80 at the IP for host B. The configuration for this depends on what host A is, and what software is running on it.